# Flex 3: get all files of a folder in an array

Tags: apache-flex, file, directory

How can i get all the files in a given folder in flex project. the folder is within the project itself, under src folder, like

src>
 images>
    image1.jpg,
    image2.jpg,
    ....
    imagen.jpg

I want to get the names of all jpg file in an array.. how it can be done programmaticly?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using AIR, you can do it via [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class. Otherwise you can do it via [FileReferenceList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReferenceList.html), (`browse()` method, then select all and you'll get array of `FileReference` objects).

Comment: Another way to do it is to have an xml file with the images you want to display and have Flex load/parse that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fileDirectry:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("C:/Users/temp");

var files:Array = fileDirectry.getDirectoryListing();
for each(var file:File in files)
{
}
```